# JavaFX controller's two initialize methods

Tags: java, javafx

I just realized i have two initalize methods that are in my controller class.

One is created by Scene Builder and makes no requirement on class to implement `Initializable` interface.

```
@FXML
void initialize()
{
    assert birthDate != null
            : "fx:id=\"birthDate\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'baptismEntryView.fxml'.";
    assert baptismDate != null
            : "fx:id=\"baptismDate\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'baptismEntryView.fxml'.";
    ...
}
```

Other one with two parameters needs to implement `Initalizable` interface

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{
    ...
}
```

I see that there is difference, that initialize that requires to implement Initializable interface allows me to access ResourceBundle during creation of controller for example.

What i want to ask is in what order they are called and what everything I am supposed to do in them (maybe some docs/tutorial reference?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have both. I can't find documentation on this, but it appears that if the controller implements `Initializable` then the no-arg `initialize()` method is never invoked.

It's actually [recommended](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) you don't implement `Initializable`:

> *NOTE* This interface has been superseded by automatic injection of `location` and `resources` properties into the controller. `FXMLLoader` will now automatically call any suitably annotated no-arg `initialize()` method defined by the controller. It is recommended that the injection approach be used whenever possible.

If you still need access to the `ResourceBundle` (and/or location `URL`) then you can do the following:

```java
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class Controller {
  
  // you don't need to declare both 'location' and 'resources'
  @FXML private URL location;
  @FXML private ResourceBundle resources;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: So that URL and ResourceBundle are injected? I assume if i dont pass ResourceBundle to FXMLLoader, it will be null.

Comment: Correct. They're injected just like any other FXML-injected field (e.g. labels, buttons, etc.) before the `initialize` method is invoked.

Comment: I don't see why they did not mark `Initializable` interface as deprecated then when it has been superseded by this auto injection.

Comment: _mark Initializable interface as deprecated_ good suggestion, you might consider filing an RFE :) On the other hand, it's not overly important as long as devs read the java doc <g>

Comment: @kleopatra I think someone should also suggest making the "injection approach" better documented. It's never explicitly described what the names of the fields need to be (i.e. `location` and `resources`). You have to infer it from that note in the `Initializable` Javadoc by the fact the words "location" and "resources" is styled as inline code. As far as I know there's no mention of the injection approach in the _Introduction to FXML_ document. In fact, I feel that whole document needs a rewrite...

Comment: I'm actually not sure why there's a separate _Introduction to FXML_ document anyway. Seems like the package Javadoc of `javafx.fxml` and/or the class Javadoc of `FXMLLoader` would be a better place for most of that information.

Comment: @Wortig My guess is because `Initializable` is not truly obsolete and they only recommend the injection approach for consistency with how everything else works. But maybe it was an oversight and the interface should be deprecated.

Comment: I agree with all your points, Slaw - the auto-injection of location/resourcebundle was news to me (not using fxml too often) - go ahead and contribute :))

Comment: I remember posting a RFE for better documentation of `FXMLLoader` about 6 years ago. It was closed as "won't fix". There is a lot of functionality not documented at all, such as the controller factory and namespace. Maybe now Gluon have taken over dev they may be more interested in doing this?

Comment: [Here's](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091235) the bug report I filed, seven years ago. It's actually "unresolved".